# Have droids ever had a romantic relationship?

Tags: star-wars, droids

Have two *Star Wars* droids ever been in a relationship together, either in-canon, questionable canon or not-canon?

Comment: id like to spill my oil on your nice looking bolts

Comment: @Himarm lololol

Comment: If "not-canon" includes fan-fiction, then I'm sure the answer is "Yes"...

Comment: @Adeptus that was my thought, but I can't think if any such fan fics.

Comment: eww, don't be gross

Comment: @RedCaio - we are discussing the franchise where incest and interspecies sexual slavery are more prominent than on Game of Thrones.... ewww is par for the course.

Comment: @DVK incest?... if you're talking about Luke/Leia, that never happened. It was just kissing, nothing else. (which is still gross)

Comment: Yes, C-3P0 and RD-D2 are friends, they are in a friendship.

Comment: @RedCaio  - relationship that never progresses to sex is still a relationship :)

Comment: Dvk should have clarified, I meant romantic.

Comment: @DVK relationship yes, incest no. relationship __≠__ incest, they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Um, neither like not leia are droids?

Comment: Considering all sorts of other things that can be found, I'm sure there's porn of it somewhere. That counts as fan-fiction, right?

Comment: It's been whispered that C-3PO & Dot Matrix had a short, but lurid affair at ludicrous speed.

Comment: According to this Simpsons clip, the robots from Star Wars are gay, so yes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDGX8WCVfwg

Comment: @sjuan Geonosis. Which is even more Paris like than you think: that's where Ani and Padme went to declare their love.

Answer (score 19):

## Yes.

- R2-D2 and [KT-10](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/KT-10) (*Star Wars: Droids*)
- C-3PO and [LE-914/Ellie](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/LE-914) is a possibility - he cried when she died (*Star Wars #80*)

## Bonus round: Organic meatbags vs. Droids:

- [C8-42-GE3](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/C8-42-GE3) was the object of romantic affection of Elise Montagne. No, this was NOT a fanfic - it happens in *Knights of the Old Republic*.

You can read all about these, and other weird romantic relationships in TGFFA (Luke and Leia nonwithstanding), in <strike>fanfiction.net</strike> starwars.com blog article ["I’d Just as Soon Kiss a Wookiee: Star Wars Romances"](http://www.starwars.com/news/id-just-as-soon-kiss-a-wookiee-star-wars-romances)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! I'll leave this question open a little longer to see if anyone else knows any more relationships. EDIT: How did C-3PO cry??

Comment: @ThomasShera - that's generally a good strategy, to leave answers unaccepted for a while. Some people do so for months (myself included, though sometiems out of laziness :). The best answer isn't always posted the first day or even week.

Comment: thanks, I am new to this forum so I wasn't sure if that was a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasShera - also, in case you didn't know, you can always change which answer is the accepted one later on.

Comment: Well, I would say that the KOTOR example is only implied to be romantic - albeit very *strongly* implied.

Comment: Re R2-D2 & KT-10 link: "spray oil at each other". Is that a euphemism?

Comment: What is TGFFA? Google returns nothing that applies.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89 *The Galaxy Far Far Away*